# Taylor double series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

For the domain $\{(x+y): -1 < x + y < 1\}$ consider the function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1 - (x+y)}$$

This can be expanded as a convergent geometric series

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(x+y)^n$$

I also see that $(x+y)^n$ can be further expanded as $\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}x^i y^{n-i}$.

But how does this relate to the Taylor expansion around (0,0):

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m= 0}^\infty \frac{\partial^{n+m}f}{\partial^n x \partial^m y}(0,0) \frac{x^ny^m}{n!m!}$$

Are the single and double series the same thing with the same convergence domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double Taylor series for $f(x,y) = (1 - x - y)^{-1}$ around the origin is

$$\tag{1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left.\frac{\partial^{n+m}f}{\partial^nx \partial^m y}\right|_{(0,0)}\frac{x^ny^m}{n!m!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!} x^ny^m.$$

On the other hand, using the binomial theorem we have the expansion

$$\tag{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+y)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}x^ky^{m-k}.$$

Series (1) and (2) are related in that partial sums of (2) coincide with partial sums of (1) taken in a specific order -- summing along diagonals of the matrix $[a_{nm}]$ of general terms.

If the double series (1) is absolutely convergent, then (1) and (2) will converge to the same value.

*However, domains of convergence are not identical.* For (2) we have absolute convergence for $|x + y| < 1$, as you mentioned, and divergence for $|x+y| \geqslant 1$. This is simply a property of the geometric series.

Determining the convergence domain for (1) is more involved. For positive integers $N$ and $M$, the partial sums satisfy

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{m= 0}^M \frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}|x|^n|y|^m < \sum_{n =0}^{N+M}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} |x)^k |y|^{n-k} = \sum_{n = 0}^{N+M} (|x| + |y|)^n$$

which should be apparent because every term on the LHS appears on the RHS along with additional terms.

Thus, (1) is absolutely convergent for $|x| + |y| < 1$, and using a similarly constructed lower bound not absolutely convergent if $|x| + |y| \geqslant 1$. The case where $|x + y| < 1 < |x| + |y|$ can arise where the series are not both absolutely convergent.